# How to use one icon as texture in Autodesk Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I'm referring to this sample project
https://github.com/wallabyway/markupExt/blob/9d73779b32cad3847e8ad7bf31307b11af5a36c4/docs/markupExt.js

This samples uses a png file(img/icons.png) which has four different markups.

```
    this.vertexShader = `
        uniform float size;
        varying vec3 vColor;
        void main() {
            vColor = color;
            vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
            gl_PointSize = size * ( size / (length(mvPosition.xyz) + 1.0) );
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
        }
    `

    this.fragmentShader = `
        uniform sampler2D tex;
        varying vec3 vColor;
        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = vec4( vColor.x, vColor.x, vColor.x, 1.0 );
            gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D(tex, vec2((gl_PointCoord.x+vColor.y*1.0)/4.0, 1.0-gl_PointCoord.y));
            if (gl_FragColor.w < 0.5) discard;
        }
    `
```

```
// create new point cloud material
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("img/icons.png");
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
    fragmentShader: this.fragmentShader,
    vertexShader: this.vertexShader,
    depthWrite: true,
    depthTest: true,
    uniforms: {
        size: { type: "f", value: this.size },
        tex: { type: "t", value: texture }
    }
});
```

I want to use one markup in a png file.
How can you fix this?

Comment: Let me look into this …

Answer (score 0):

Modify the PNG containing 4 icons.  Place your icon over the top of the first icon.  Then you can remove the other 3.